# p:dataTable select all checkbox

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function sellectAll(datatable) {
            var checked = $(document).find(":checkbox")["5"].checked; ///Find checkbox header and verify if checkbox is checked
            if (checked === true) {
                PF(datatable).selectAllRows(); // if true, selectAllRows from datatable
            } else {
                PF(datatable).unselectAllRows(); //
            }


        }
    </script>
```

data table

```
    <p:dataTable  value="#{itemCardWithoutCostBean.warehousesList}" widgetVar="warehouseList" selection="#{itemCardWithoutCostBean.selectedWarehouses}" rowKey="#{warehouse.warehouseCode}" 
                                      rows="10" paginator="true" 
                                      styleClass="ui-datatable-hor-scroll" scrollWidth="100%" paginatorPosition="bottom" var="warehouse">
                           <p:ajax  event="toggleSelect" oncomplete="sellectAll(warehouseList)" />
```

select all is working if there are only one datatable, but if the page have more than one datatable deselect all not work after i deselect datatable which i have checked first

Comment: why doing something in JS since you can do it in your jsf managedBean ?!? please add your datatble structur i think it will help

Comment: i added data table structure

Comment: i see change `oncomplete` with `onclick`

Comment: onclick not support in Ajax component

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to call a client side method (you JS method) with a server side method

Comment: you can replace it by a managedBean method it's more simple

Comment: Since you are using a paginator you must use, as @YagamiLight suggested, a component managed solution. Add to your datatable the following column: `<p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>` and check how it works in the [documentation page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml). Remember that you are using a component based framework therefore you should work with it. I'm not saying you should not use javascript, but you should avoid it when you can.